# Dismissing view using delegation not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, protocols

I am trying to use delegation, which I am new at, to dismiss a modally presented view. I am trying to get it to work along the lines of the apple documentation seen [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers.html). So far my code is as follows:

1. Put both views on storyboard, connect first to second view with modal segue. (the segue to view2 works fine)
2. create delegate inside second viewcontroller/create method to call when returned:

   ```
   //inside of view2ViewController.h
   @class view2ViewController;
   @protocol view2ViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
   -(void)goBack:(OptionsViewController *)controller;
   @end

   @interface OptionsViewController : UIViewController
   @property (nonatomic, weak) id <view2ViewControllerDelegate>delegate;
   - (IBAction)return:(id)sender;//connected to button
   @end
   ```
3. implement delegate in view1ViewController `@interface view1ViewController : UIViewController <view2ViewControllerDelegate>`
4. write code for delegate method goBack in view1Controller.m

   ```
   -(void)goBack:(view2ViewController *)controller{
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];}
   ```
5. finish by writing code for return method in view2ViewController.m

   ```
   - (IBAction)return:(id)sender {
   [self.delegate goBack:self];}
   ```

I'm not sure where this code is going wrong. The return method is called, but then goBack isn't. I did read the developer documentation, and thought I understood, but I guess not...

PS I change the names of all of my class/variable names on StackOverflow to be more generic, so if there is a slight discrepancy between variable name spellings, it's probably because i typed one wrong.

Comment: Are you doing this for practice? Because otherwise BY FAR the easiest way to dismiss a modal view controller is to link up your go back button to an ib action which uses [self dismissModalViewController animated:YES];

Comment: yes essentially I am doing it for practice. I need to use it later to pass information back to my other view, but I'm starting off simple. I also need it for some non-modal segues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best shot I can try -

Make sure you assigned the SplashViewController as the delegate of the view2ViewController.

By code you can do it  like that (in the SplashViewController m file):

```
view2ViewController.delegate = self;
```

Or you can do to on Story board.

**BTW**
I a not sure calling your function "return" is a good idea.

Comment: That was in fact the problem! I didn't know I needed to do that, but it makes sense (of course). My function isn't actually called return, I changed it to make my code more generic on StackOverflow. Just curious, how would I do that on the Storyboard instead of with code?

Comment: I am usually making my view programmatically so I am not sure. Try right click the file owner of your view2ViewController. you might see there a "delegate", drag it to your SplashViewController? But I am not sure.